# How to change excludeFromRecents value during runtime

Tags: android, android-activity

In my root activity I use the following

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

But for some devices it's important to show the root activity in the recent list, and I want to give the user the ability to change **excludeFromRecents** to be false.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it's not possible to change that during runtime.